# How to route multiple controllers in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got error "Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file"

I have two controllers 1.signup and 2.login_control !

How to set routes in routes.php file ? my baseurl is http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/

my code is below in routes.php file

```
$route['signup/(:any)'] = 'signup';
$route['login_control/(:any)'] = 'login_control';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, specified your default route by your first controller.

Like this-

```
$route['default_controller'] = "signup";
```

and then add your another controller.

```
$route['login-control'] = 'login_control';
```

Comment: I have done like this but my ajax call is not working ! when I put login_control as default_controller its working nicely ! my ajax url is http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/ when default controller is signup ! for login_controller it should be like this ? http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/login_control

Comment: Your url should look like this -  localhost:1337/PhpProject1/login-control

Comment: it is solved by this url http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/index.php/login_control

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

**Syntax**

```
$route['how_its_look_like'] = 'controller_name/method';
```

**Example**

```
$route['signup'] = 'login/signup';
$route['login'] = 'login/login';
$route['logout'] = 'login/logout';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Links**

[Ccodeigniter Routing Examples](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routes#examples)